# Best tool to do stress test for a Restful API protected with OAuth 2.0?

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0

I need to perform stress tests on a Restful API that uses OAuth 2.0 security. The authorization process involves a basic authentication followed by an authorization grant page.

Can someone direct me to the best tool to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use RestAssured for that or Gattling.